# Disabling a button via JS if a specific element ID appears on page

Tags: javascript, button, disable

I am trying to use JS to change an add to cart button to be disabled if our inventory level (displayed on the front end in a `<span>`) is "out of stock". This JS is already set up on our site for changing button behaviour for variants (code at the bottom of the post) and so if I can integrate an additional conditional rule using our inventory `<span>` that would be amazing.

Here's the HTML for when the out of stock message appears:

```
<span class="LocationNoStock">Currently Sold Out</span>
```

I honestly have almost zero experience with JS so all I know is that I can look for elements by class name:

```
(document.getElementsByClassName("LocationNoStock")
```

Basically I want to add logic that dictates:

```
if class 'LocationNoStock' exists then disable 'add-to-cart' button
```

Any help that can be offered would be much appreciated! If it helps, our current JS for modifying the add-to-cart button is as follows - if an additional rule to search for the `<span>` could be inserted and mimic the behaviour that would be amazing!

```
updateCartButton: function(evt) {
var variant = evt.variant;
if (variant) {
if (variant.available) {
// Available, enable the submit button and change text
$(selectors.addToCart, this.$container).removeClass(classes.disabled).prop('disabled', false);
$(selectors.addToCartText, this.$container).html(theme.strings.addToCart);
} else {
// Sold out, disable the submit button and change text
$(selectors.addToCart, this.$container).addClass(classes.disabled).prop('disabled', true);
$(selectors.addToCartText, this.$container).html(theme.strings.soldOut);
}
} else {
// The variant doesn't exist, disable submit button
$(selectors.addToCart, this.$container).addClass(classes.disabled).prop('disabled', true);
$(selectors.addToCartText, this.$container).html(theme.strings.unavailable);
}
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable buttonin javascript on load, can be done by setting attribute  of the element
Example :
setAttribute("style","color:red")
In your case you are fetching element using class "add-to-cart" which gives htmlcollection so using index you can access the button element and then using setAttribute function of javascript, can set particular properties.

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 if (document.getElementsByClassName("LocationNoStock") != null){
     var element = document.getElementsByClassName("add-to-cart");
     
    element[0].setAttribute("disabled", ""); 
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using jquery `$(...)` so you could do the following, look for `.LocationNoStock` if it's found then disable the `.add-to-cart` button.

```js
 if ($('.LocationNoStock').length) $('.add-to-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="LocationNoStock">Currently Sold Out</span>
<button type="button" class="add-to-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```